# Pie chart slice not matching percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a pie chart using ggplot2 but the pie chart slices are not matching the legend percentages.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0FjM.png)

```
`  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  library(officer)

  # Read in data from CSV file
  data1 <- read.csv("data11.csv")

  # Create a new Word document
  doc <- read_docx()


  # Get unique primary breeds
  data2 <- unique(data1$Primary.Breed)

  # Define color palette for the pie chart
  colors <- c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7", "#999999")

  # Define vector of dates
  dates <- as.Date(c("01/01/2010", "01/01/2011", "01/01/2012", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2014", "01/01/2015", "01/01/2016", "01/01/2017", "01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/01/2020", "01/01/2021", "01/01/2022", "01/01/2023"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")

  # Define age categories and corresponding labels
  age_categories <- c("Less than three Months", "Between 3 months and 6 months", "Between 6 months and 12 months", "Greater than 12 months")
  AgeCategorySex <- c("Less than three Months M", "Less than three Months F", "Between 3 months and 6 months M", "Between 3 months and 6 months F", "Between 6 months and 12 months M", "Between 6 months and 12 months F", "Greater than 12 months M", "Greater than 12 months F")

  # Convert DateOfBirth column to Date format
  data1$DateOfBirth <- as.Date(data1$DateOfBirth, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

  # Loop through each breed
  for (breed in data2) {
    breed_data <- subset(data1, Primary.Breed == breed)
    
    # Initialize vector to store counts for each age category sex
    age_counts <- rep(0, length(AgeCategorySex))
    
    # Add AgeCategory column and initialize it
    breed_data$AgeCategory <- NA
    
    # Calculate difference in days between each birth date and each date in the vector
    for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
      date2 <- dates[i]
      
      # Reset age counts for each date
      age_counts <- rep(0, length(AgeCategorySex))
      
      # Calculate age category for each record
      for (j in 1:nrow(breed_data)) {
        diff <- as.numeric(difftime(date2, breed_data$DateOfBirth[j], units = "days"))
         if (!is.na(diff) && diff>0)
        if (!is.na(diff) && diff < 90 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "M") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Less than three Months M"
          age_counts[1] <- age_counts[1] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff < 90 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "F") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Less than three Months F"
          age_counts[2] <- age_counts[2] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 90 && diff < 180 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "M") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Between 3 months and 6 months M"
          age_counts[3] <- age_counts[3] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 90 && diff < 180 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "F") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Between 3 months and 6 months F"
          age_counts[4] <- age_counts[4] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 180 && diff < 365 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "M") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Between 6 months and 12 months M"
          age_counts[5] <- age_counts[5] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 180 && diff < 365 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "F") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Between 6 months and 12 months F"
          age_counts[6] <- age_counts[6] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 365 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "M") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Greater than 12 months M"
          age_counts[7] <- age_counts[7] + 1
        } else if (!is.na(diff) && diff >= 365 && breed_data$Sex[j] == "F") {
          breed_data$AgeCategory[j] <- "Greater than 12 months F"
          age_counts[8] <- age_counts[8] + 1
        }
      }
      
      # Calculate total count
      total_count <- sum(age_counts)
      
      # Calculate percentages
      percentages <- paste0(round((age_counts / total_count) * 100, 2), "%")
      
      # Create the pie chart using ggplot2
      chart_title <- paste("Pie chart for", breed, "on", as.character(dates[i]), "(Total:", total_count, ")")
      pie_data <- data.frame(AgeCategorySex, Count = age_counts)
      chart <- ggplot(pie_data, aes(x = "", y = Count, fill = AgeCategorySex)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
        labs(title = chart_title) +
        theme_void()
      
      # Add custom legend with percentages
      custom_legend <- paste(pie_data$AgeCategorySex, percentages, sep = " - ")
      chart <- chart + guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Age Category (Percentage)")) +
        scale_fill_discrete(labels = custom_legend)
      
      
      
      
      # Save the plot as a PNG file with increased width
      ggsave(filename = paste0(breed, "_plot", date2, ".png"), plot = chart, width = 10, height = 4)
      
      # Add the plot image to the Word document
      doc <- body_add_img(doc, src = paste0(breed, "_plot", date2, ".png"), width = 7, height = 4)
      
      # Print plot for current month and breed
      print(chart)
    }
  }

  # Save the Word document
  print(doc, target = "Plot.docx")
```

The above code plots a pie chart but percentages in legend are not matching pie chart slices. I am using ggplot2 to plot. What can be the cause of the problem? Legend colors and pie chart slice size  are not matching.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please make your code *minimal* and *reproducible*.  Minimal: we don't need all the data manipulation prior to creating the plot.  Nor anything to do with writing to your word document.  Reproducible: we need to see `pie_data`.  Please use `dput`.

Comment: But without the data manipulation it won't be reproducible...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example - you don't need to reproduce your exact data, just a toy example showing the issue.  in your case it's just the plot that's causing an issue, so an example dataset AFTER all the data manipulation would be fine.